# Dichotomy in society

Tags: sociology

I am not a student of sociology but I wish to know if there is any theory of society where we can study the dichotomy in a sociological aspect. Take for example, in a country where there is a crackdown on child marriages on one side not covered by media and on the other side, there is a fat wedding of two millionares being covered extensively by the media.

How do we study these two sides of the coin (coin of marriage) and an external field (media coverage) that is quite biased in my opinion.

Comment: Do you have some more examples? I'm not quite getting it. Rich people will always behave very differently and get lots of media coverage.

Comment: @Scott Rowe : I request SE to reopen the question. I would like to elaborate on this. I had posted this questions since I believed philosophy and sociology are interlinked somewhere. My question was driven by the book by Amartya Sen's "Collective Choice and Social Welfare".

Comment: Yes. I didn't vote to close the question. You can edit, be sure to quote your references. Then click the Flag link "for moderator attention" and explain that you have improved the question. They might reopen it. Good luck!